# Mysql variable max_allowed_packet and max size of a query

Tags: php, mysql

I understand that the variable max_allowed_packet contains the maximum size of a mysql query. I have a problem with my linux server, i've set this value on 1G, and after some time the variable is set with a minor value, and i need to set the variable again. Also, i set the variable in the my.cnf file.

I want to know why this is happening.

Could it be that the queries i'm making are bigger than the 1G value set in the variable?

Is there a way i can know the size of a query? (update, insert and select)

Thank you so much!

Comment: This may answer your query. Maybe you are getting caught out because you only set the Server side and not the client side http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45106/50180

Comment: @RiggsFolly i understand. Is there a particular way i can change it on the client side? Or that depends on how is structured my program?

Comment: I think the client side only applies if you are usinf tools like mysql.exe

Answer (score 0):

hi you can set this with the documentation official mysql
check this

[max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)

```
shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
```

try with this